# Optimizar generación excel grande c#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Generé un archivo excel de aproximadamente 155 mil filas y 100 columnas, lo que hago es ir agregando a un datatable las columnas y las filas y al último genero el archivo excel con epplus, quisiera saber si hay una manera de poder eficientar el proceso, ya que consume mucha memoria el datatable.

```
using (var msReporte = new MemoryStream())
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String("")))
            {
                var licenseForCells = new License();
                licenseForCells.SetLicense(ms);

                var workbookForDataTable = new Workbook();
                var importOptions = new ImportTableOptions();
                var dataTableWorksheet = workbookForDataTable.Worksheets[0];

                dataTableWorksheet.Cells.ImportData(reporte, 0, 0, importOptions);
                dataTableWorksheet.AutoFitColumns();
                workbookForDataTable.Save(msReporte, SaveFormat.Xlsx);

                return new ReportesModel { Archivo = msReporte.ToArray(), Nombre = $"Reporte_Nomina_{query.FechaInicioDt:ddMMyyyy}_{query.FechaFinDt:ddMMyyyy}.xlsx" };
            }
```

En mi código reporte es el datatable.

Comment: Si la respuesta que te dieron solucionó tu escenario, márcala como aceptada (click en el check verde del costado de la respuesta), de este modo ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias intentar hacerlo de otra forma en la que consumira menos memoria.
En lugar de cargar todas las 155 mil filas y 100 columnas de una vez, podrías procesar los datos por lotes

```
int batchSize = 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < msReporte.Rows.Count; i += batchSize)
{
    DataTable batchTable = msReporte.Clone();
    for (int j = 0; j < batchSize && i + j < msReporte.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        batchTable.ImportRow(msReporte.Rows[i + j]);
    }

    // Procesar batchTable y agregarlo al worksheet
    AgregarBatchAlWorksheet(batchTable, dataTableWorksheet);

}

// Método para agregar el lote al worksheet
private void AgregarBatchAlWorksheet(DataTable batchTable, Worksheet worksheet)
{
    int startingRow = worksheet.Cells.MaxDataRow + 1;

    // Crear un rango de celdas para el lote
    var cellStart = worksheet.Cells[startingRow, 0];
    var cellEnd = worksheet.Cells[startingRow + batchTable.Rows.Count - 1, batchTable.Columns.Count - 1];
    var range = worksheet.Cells[cellStart.Address + ":" + cellEnd.Address];

    // Importar datos al rango
    range.LoadFromDataTable(batchTable, true);

    // Autoajustar las columnas después de importar datos
    worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
}
```

Con el EPPLUS no neceseriamente tendrias que usar DataTable

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("NombreDeTuHoja");

    // Agregar datos directamente al worksheet sin DataTable
    
    package.SaveAs(msReporte);
}
```

Si sigues optar por usar DT, optimizalo de esta forma

// Eliminar columnas no deseadas

```
foreach (DataColumn column in reporte.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray())
{
    if (!columnasNecesarias.Contains(column.ColumnName))
        reporte.Columns.Remove(column);
}
```

Espero te sirva! saludos